# Plotting a weekly time series for multiple districts together

Tags: r, plot, time-series, timeserieschart

I have a dataframe like this which contains information of 52 weeks of 100 districts in India. A sample dataframe is attached below, however this extends to 52 weeks and 100 districts(Eg.-Viala, Barontha and so on).

```
    "Block" 01 Jan/ 05 Jan  06 Jan/ 12 Jan  13 Jan/ 19 Jan  20 Jan/ 26 Jan
        1   2   3   4
Viala   9   11  4   0
Barontha    0   0   0   0
Dasau   4   29  17  9
Kwanu   2   123 62  11
```

I wish to represent this as a time series data frame and also plot it.
I used the following code:

```
stools=read.csv("~/stoolwithdehyd.csv",header=TRUE)
stools[is.na(stools)] <- 0
stooltimeseries <- ts(stools, frequency=52)
plot.ts(stooltimeseries)
```

But i got the following error

```
Error in plotts(x = x, y = y, plot.type = plot.type, xy.labels = xy.labels,  : 
cannot plot more than 10 series as "multiple"
```

I saw another user suffering from a similar error and modified my code using the given answer to

```
library(reshape2)    
mm = melt(stooltimeseries, id='id')
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mm)+geom_line(aes(x=variable, y=value, group=id, color=id))
plot.ts(stooltimeseries)
```

The time series got plotted but not according to what I wanted and also got an error

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found
```

[image: Image of the time series I got]

However what I want is to plot the numbers on the y axis with the corresponding weeks on the x axis and have one line or plot for every district. If anyone could help

```
dput(stools[1:4,1:5])

structure(list(Block. = structure(c(1L, 103L, 19L, 28L), .Label = c(" ", 
" Balawala", " Bhaniawala", " Doiwala", " Dudhli", " Herbetpur", 
" Raiwala", " Ranipokhari", " SPD Indira Nagar Colony", " UHP D.L Road", 
" UHP Dalanwala", " UHP Dobhalwala", " UHP Khurbura", " UHP Patel Nagar", 
"Ajabpur", "Asan Bag", "Ashtad", "Badripur", "Barontha", "Bhagwampur", 
"Bhatta", "Bhogpur", "Buraswa", "Byas Bhoor", "Chadroti", "Charba", 
"Chidderwala", "Dasau", "Dhaki", "Dhakrani", "Dhalipur", "Dharmawala", 
"Dilau", "Dwara Samoli", "Fatehpur", "garhi", "Gaziawala", "Gumaniwala", 
"Hakikat Rai Nagar", "Hariyawala khurd", "Jahdi", "Jakhan", "Jamnipur", 
"Jassowala", "Johdi", "Juddo", "Kamla", "Kanwali", "Kaulagarh", 
"Keinchiwala", "Kettri", "Khatar", "Khunna", "Korba", "Kunjagrant", 
"Kwansi", "Kwanu", "Lelta", "Mairavana", "Majra", "Majri", "Malsi", 
"Manthat", "Matiyawa", "MCH  Herbetpur", "MCH Rudrapur", "Mehuwala", 
"Mohana", "Naraya", "Nehrugram", "Pashchimwala", "Pelion ", "PHC Kalsi", 
"Pipaya", "Rajawala", "Rampur", "Rikhad", "Rural Health Center", 
"Sabhawala", "Sahaspur", "Sahiya", "Samalta", "Sauda Saroli", 
"Sawra", "Seinj", "Selaqui", "Sewala Kala", "Sherpur", "SPD Adhoiwala", 
"SPD Bhagat Singh Colony", "Sureu", "Telpura", "Thano", "Tyuni", 
"UHC Ajabpur", "UHC Kanwali/Seemadwar", "UHC Kishan Nagar", "UHC Majra", 
"UHC Rece Course", "UHP Ballupur", "UHP Dharampur", "UHP Reetha Mandi", 
"Viala", "Vitrali"), class = "factor"), X01.Jan..05.Jan = c(1, 
0, 0, 0), X06.Jan..12.Jan = c(2, 0, 0, 0), X13.Jan..19.Jan = c(3, 
0, 0, 0), X20.Jan..26.Jan = c(4, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Block.", 
"X01.Jan..05.Jan", "X06.Jan..12.Jan", "X13.Jan..19.Jan", "X20.Jan..26.Jan"
), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you put a 'dput' of your data? They're not very easily imported by copying and pasting. And did the call to ggplot also not give you the desired results?

Comment: @Heroka the dput is exceeding the maximum character limit by 21000 characters so I've edited the data frame accordingly, no on executing ggplot is got the error that Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found

Comment: Please do 'dput(head(mydata))` then?

Comment: @Heroka still too long by 4267 characters

Comment: dput(mydata([1:4,1:5]))?

Comment: @Heroka I've added it to the questions section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help for the plotting part. I've used ggplot as the ts.plot appears to not be able to plot more than 10. Then it's just a question of getting your data in the right format for plotting.

```
#make new dataframe with week numbers as column headers
stools2 <- stools[-1,]
colnames(stools2) <- c("Block",stools[1,][-1])

#now make things up, as all data are zero in your example
set.seed(1)
stools2[stools2==0] <- sample(1:12,sum(stools2==0),T)

#melt the data
library(reshape2)
stools_melt <- melt(stools2, id.var="Block", variable.name="week")
stools_melt$week <- as.numeric(stools_melt$week)

#plot
p1 <- ggplot(stools_melt, aes(x=week,y=value,group=Block, color=Block)) + geom_line()
p1
```

Comment: thank you, works all right. I have a query, can you please explain this colnames(stools2) <- c("Block",stools[1,][-1]), specially the use of the indices[1,][-1]